# Create custom matrix from values coming out of vector calculations using only the highest number

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Hello, I have a problem and I have absolutely no idea how to tackle this...

I have a dataframe:

```
LK  BALG    AMRU    CADZ
11  0,000   0,004   0,000
12  0,000   0,010   0,000
13  0,000   0,034   0,000
14  0,000   0,076   0,000
15  0,001   0,134   0,000
16  0,001   0,211   0,000
17  0,002   0,294   0,000
18  0,007   0,370   0,008
19  0,012   0,434   0,030
20  0,023   0,509   0,054
21  0,040   0,566   0,080
22  0,075   0,628   0,229
23  0,109   0,697   0,363
24  0,140   0,770   0,435
25  0,178   0,828   0,493
26  0,219   0,876   0,536
27  0,260   0,906   0,575
28  0,301   0,929   0,625
29  0,353   0,954   0,660
30  0,405   0,968   0,715
31  0,480   0,978   0,769
```

First step I want to calculate the values of subtracting BALG by AMRU and etc.. Getting something like this:

```
LK  BALG-AMRU   BALG-CADZ   CADZ-AMRU
11  0,004       0,000       0,004
12  0,010       0,000       0,010
13  0,034       0,000       0,034
14  0,076       0,000       0,076
15  0,134       0,001       0,134
16  0,210       0,001       0,211
17  0,292       0,002       0,294
18  0,363       0,000       0,362
19  0,422       0,017       0,404
20  0,486       0,030       0,456
21  0,526       0,040       0,486
22  0,553       0,154       0,399
23  0,588       0,254       0,334
24  0,630       0,295       0,335
25  0,650       0,315       0,334
26  0,658       0,317       0,341
27  0,646       0,315       0,331
28  0,628       0,325       0,303
29  0,601       0,306       0,295
30  0,563       0,310       0,253
31  0,499       0,290       0,209
```

After doing this:

Second step:

I want to create a matrix (like a correlation matrix) with having only the highest numbers of the created vectors as matrix values.

In this case:

```
0,650 for BALG-AMRU
0,325 for BALG-CADZ
0,486 for CADZ-AMRU
```

I have no idea how to start this..any help is very very welcome. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to do this

```
out <- do.call(cbind, combn(df1[-1], 2, 
     FUN = function(x) x[1] - x[2], simplify = FALSE))
colnames(out) <- combn(names(df1)[-1], 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "-")
out1 <- cbind(df1[1], out)
```

Then, get the `max` on the `abs` values

```
sapply(abs(out1[-1]), max)
BALG-AMRU BALG-CADZ AMRU-CADZ 
    0.657     0.324     0.486
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(LK = 11:31, BALG = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.001, 0.001, 
0.002, 0.007, 0.012, 0.023, 0.04, 0.075, 0.109, 0.14, 0.178, 
0.219, 0.26, 0.301, 0.353, 0.405, 0.48), AMRU = c(0.004, 0.01, 
0.034, 0.076, 0.134, 0.211, 0.294, 0.37, 0.434, 0.509, 0.566, 
0.628, 0.697, 0.77, 0.828, 0.876, 0.906, 0.929, 0.954, 0.968, 
0.978), CADZ = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.008, 0.03, 0.054, 0.08, 
0.229, 0.363, 0.435, 0.493, 0.536, 0.575, 0.625, 0.66, 0.715, 
0.769)), row.names = c(NA, -21L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That is a very nice solution! Thank you! My real dataset consists of 23 vectors. So I'll give it a go..and let you know when I get in trouble ;)